# set up mongo db on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, mongodb

I am trying to set up ruby on rails application with  mongodb
I have done the steps written in this link http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Rails+3+-+Getting+Started   and still i am not able to run my rails application. When I try to generate a controller or migration I get this error

```
C:\Users\Abhay\Documents\NetBeansProjects\my_app>rails generate controller demo
C:/Users/Abhay/Documents/NetBeansProjects/my_app/config/initializers/mongo.rb:1:
 uninitialized constant MongoMapper (NameError)
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.r
 b:201
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.r
 b:200:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.r
 b:200
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initiali
 zable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initiali
  zable.rb:25:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initiali
  zable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initiali
  zable.rb:49:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initiali
    zable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/applicat
   ion.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/applicat
   ion.rb:77:in `send'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/applicat
   ion.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from C:/Users/Abhay/Documents/NetBeansProjects/my_app/config/environment
     .rb:5
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/applicat
   ion.rb:103:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/applicat
   ion.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands
    .rb:16
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Comment: Is mongomapper added to your gemfile and did you run `bundle install`? What does `bundle show mongo_mapper` say?

Comment: yes, I have done both. My bundle has mongomapper installed.

Comment: Thanks for you help now I am moving to mongoid

Comment: I just realized that you did not run rails withing bundler. Maybe you should have called `bundle exec rails generate controller demo` instead.

Comment: I have moved to mongoid and its great. Thank you once again for your interest